# PHP framework and shared hosting with ftp inside only the public_html

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

lately I'm trying to learn php frameworks, cause I want to implement them in my projects, implement routes and secure sessions/form handling and I'm sick of using wordpress for client's works, so I discovered Slim, and I made the example app that you can find in the project's homepage.

Now, for various reasons, I know a lot of client will end up opting for a shared hosting solution, when it's just a showcase website, so I made some research about shared hosting configuration and .htaccess file. I used altervista to make a test and see if it works (it's a free hosting service, shared), the only problem is that every tutorial I followed, assumed that when  connecting through ftp you can see the doc root (public_html, htdocs and so on) but still upload out of it, instead, in this case I can only see the inside of public folder.

This had me a little bit confused, but I tried anyway, I uploaded all slim files (including public app folder and all necessary background files), made an .htaccess, and uploaded it, that's its content :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minimaleffort.altervista.org$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.minimaleffort.altervista.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

I went to the index of my website and the home screen of slim framework appears as intended (a bit edited cause I implemented bootstrap css)

[image]

Everything works, right? No, wrong, if I type a route (for example the default app route)

```
/{name}
```

It returns a 404 error page, while it should print on screen whatever name I put in the URL, am I missing something?
If you wanna check the site directly [here's the url](http://www.minimaleffort.altervista.org)

Comment: TBH, if you can afford it, using a VPS is a lot better options. You can get one for 5$/mo.

Comment: @tereško I absolutely know that, for personal projects I have my VPS, and it's amazing, but unfortunately for me here where I live sometimes client have already bought a shared hosting plan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [official Slim 3 example application](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/example/.htaccess), its `.htaccess` file reads as following:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I am by no means a mod_rewrite guru, but I think you are not passing the query string to the index file. This is why the frontpage works, but not the other pages.

I think your `.htaccess` file should look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minimaleffort.altervista.org$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.minimaleffort.altervista.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Oh I thought that (as specified in the guide), this code works only if the htaccess is in the same folder of index.php (.htaccess ignorance here hehe), gonna try that, let's see how it goes

Comment: Amazing ! @OptimusCrime , it worked! Now the route works, I guess that's the solution, just a minor thing, my bootstrap css\js disappeared, I guess that means I have to write rules for those folders too? I've tried   'RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /public/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /public/js/$1 [QSA,L]' but it didn't work

Comment: Doesn't matter, solved adding /public to styles url, probably bad practice but hey, we do what we can, thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it worked out @K3nzie , if you have problems (other problem), I suggest opening a new question :) Good luck!